# How to create shortcut with serializable object as intent extra

Tags: android

I'm not able to create shortcut with serializable object as intent extra. How to create shortcut with custom object?

```
private void addShortcut(Intent intent, String vehicleNumber) {
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, vehicleNumber);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getContext(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Comment: Share what your code

Comment: above I added my code.